Location of used Wallpapers in 24.04
I remember finding the used wallpapers in a folder in Pictures in 22.04. What's the similar location in Ubuntu 24.04? I couldn't find any in Pictures. Thanks

Location is the same as always; though different packages can install to different locations, but still in /usr/share/backgrounds or /usr/share/wallpapers  (Ubuntu various flavors can package slightly differently as for final destination, but locations they use hasn't changed)

Thanks, in 22,04, if I open a picture and set it as wallpaper, it used to appear in Wallpaper folder in Pictures. Not happening in 24.04.

I checked and found /usr/share/backgrounds but my computer has no folder called  /usr/share/wallpapers . The backgrounds folder only has default wallpapers. Thanks.

I don't recall that happening before. I'd consider it a bug if GNOME copied my selected wallpaper to Pictures (and if it was actually happening, I suppose someone else might have reported it as a bug and got it fixed)

Depending on what ISO (Ubuntu Desktop of Ubuntu flavor) you install, you can have different default wallpapers. Likewise post-install, you can install wallpapers from different Ubuntu releases/flavors that will install the wallpapers in the locations used by the team that packaged it; this hasn't changed. I'm not aware of any using Pictures, so you may have created a link (ln) in that directory that pointed to wherever the files actually were (something you haven't yet done in 24.04) as I'm not aware of any team changes...

Some community wallpaper packages (ie. not those that come with a new install) can install within your $HOME directory; but NO Ubuntu release has done this by default

HI, I depended on this folder in Pictures to go back to old wallpapers I used. it has like 6 months old custom wallpaper I used through the image viewer > set as wallpaper.  I am not trying to find the default wallpapers. I had this behaviour in 22.04 and simply checking whether there is one in 24.04. Thanks.

If you contrast what gets installed in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop
https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/all/ubuntu-wallpapers-jammy/filelist
/usr/share/backgrounds/Blue_flower_by_Elena_Stravoravdi.jpg
/usr/share/backgrounds/Cherry_Tree_in_Lakones_by_elenastravoravdi.jpg
/usr/share/backgrounds/DSC2943_by_kcpru.jpg
/usr/share/backgrounds/Jammy-Jellyfish_WP_4096x2304_Grey.png
/usr/share/backgrounds/Mirror_by_Uday_Nakade.jpg
/usr/share/backgrounds/Optical_Fibers_in_Dark_by_Elena_Stravoravdi.jpg
/usr/share/backgrounds/canvas_by_roytanck.jpg
/usr/share/backgrounds/contest/jammy.xml
/usr/share/backgrounds/jj_dark_by_Hiking93.jpg
/usr/share/backgrounds/jj_light_by_Hiking93.jpg
/usr/share/backgrounds/ubuntu2_by_arman1992.jpg
/usr/share/backgrounds/ubuntu_by_arman1992.jpg
/usr/share/doc/ubuntu-wallpapers-jammy/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/ubuntu-wallpapers-jammy/copyright
/usr/share/gnome-background-properties/jammy-wallpapers.xml

with Ubuntu 24.04 LTS Desktop
https://packages.ubuntu.com/noble/all/ubuntu-wallpapers-noble/filelist
/usr/share/backgrounds/Clouds_by_Tibor_Mokanszki.jpg
/usr/share/backgrounds/Fuji_san_by_amaral.png
/usr/share/backgrounds/Fuwafuwa_nanbatto_san_by_amaral-dark.png
/usr/share/backgrounds/Fuwafuwa_nanbatto_san_by_amaral-light.png
/usr/share/backgrounds/Little_numbat_boy_by_azskalt.png
/usr/share/backgrounds/Monument_valley_by_orbitelambda.jpg
/usr/share/backgrounds/Northan_lights_by_mizuno.webp
/usr/share/backgrounds/Numbat_wallpaper_dimmed_3480x2160.png
/usr/share/backgrounds/Numbat_wallpaper_light_3480x2160.png
/usr/share/backgrounds/Province_of_the_south_of_france_by_orbitelambda.jpg
/usr/share/backgrounds/Rainbow_lightbulb_by_Daniel_Micallef.png
/usr/share/backgrounds/contest/noble.xml
/usr/share/doc/ubuntu-wallpapers-noble/changelog.gz
/usr/share/doc/ubuntu-wallpapers-noble/copyright
/usr/share/gnome-background-properties/noble-wallpapers.xml

you'll note the wallpapers themselves change, but not the location.
